# How to return some value from procedures in BigQuery and capture the returned value?

Tags: stored-procedures, google-bigquery, return-value, procedure

I have written a procedure (proc a) in BigQuery, and now I am writing another procedure (proc b) and I want to call (proc a) inside (proc b) and I want to define a variable in (proc b) which will be assigned by the value returned by calling (proc a).

For example: this is just to give clear idea about my question. I expect something like this ->

```
create procedure a()

begin

(SOME BODY)

(return integer value(or any other value type))

end;

create procedure b()

begin

declare i int64;

set i = call a();------------------------(What will be the exact syntax of this statement)

end;


project_name = p1
dateset_name = d1
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

There are three arguments mode you can use when defining procedure arguments

- IN indicates that the argument is only an input to the procedure. You can specify either a variable or a value expression for IN arguments.
- OUT indicates that the argument is an output of the procedure. An OUT argument is initialized to NULL when the procedure starts. You must specify a variable for OUT arguments.
- INOUT indicates that the argument is both an input to and an output from the procedure. You must specify a variable for INOUT arguments. An INOUT argument can be referenced in the body of a procedure as a variable and assigned new values.

If neither IN, OUT, nor INOUT is specified, the argument is treated as an IN argument.

So, in your case you can use either OUT or INOUT to get value back to calling script / proc

You can read more on [CREATE PROCEDURE statement](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#create_procedure)

Comment: Thank you Mikhail for replying. I have a query here that.....I have only fixed amount of argument(let's say only 3 argument, all are IN type), So, is there any way to define 4th argument as default and as a out parameter....or something like this. So, that I will define 4th variable as out parameter, but do not want to include 4th parameter while calling procedure(kind of default parameter).......And my second is about syntax of set i = call a();------------------------(What will be the exact syntax of this statement)

Comment: link in my answer has all details for any follow up questions like in above comment of yours. the main point in your original question was how to have output parameter to be used in calling script and it is answered I think :o)